# Sharepoint 2013 : Publishing site - Edit page stuck in loading

Tags: 2013, publishing-page

When a user clicks on the Edit Page button the loading notice in the upper right of the page appears and it just sits there spinning.

After 2 or 3 minutes an error message is displayed on the screen.

Using the correlation Id I found this error on the ULS log files :

> Unable to locate the WebPartAdderId for the ScriptEditorWebPart.
>   Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Le thread a été
>   abandonné.      à
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)      à
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ScriptEditorWebPart.get_WebPartAdderId()

Note that I restarted IIS but it does not resolved the issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Error is giving clue that Script editorWebpart is not working properly. Append the `?Contents=1` at then end of the URL, it will open the webpart maintinance page.
On this page you will see all the web parts being used on the Page, you can try to close the SEWebpart and then try to reload the page.